# Hibernate Search And AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, java-8, hibernate-search

Is it possible to implement Hibernate Search in AWS Lambda (Java 8) ? I am running into difficulties since Hibernate Search creates a directory for indexing which I believe isn't possible in AWS lambdas. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Locally I was able to deploy the Lambda and successfully created the directory for indexing. But whenever I deploy and trigger the lambda using Api gateway, I encounter an exception.

Comment: You should include the exact text of any exceptions in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, lambdas are supposed to be stateless, so no this probably doesn't make sense. Even if state wasn't a problem, the Lucene backend is inherently not designed for state sharing across application instances, so you'd get a rather odd behavior where no lambda sees what others indexed.

You may be able to make Hibernate Search work in a lambda if you rely on [the Elasticsearch backend](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-examples-overview), which does share state across instances by moving that state to an external Elasticsearch cluster... But I'm not sure what other problems you may encounter due to the potentially short-lived nature of lambdas.